# Optional values from Steam Web API

Tags: steam-web-api

How can I get the optional result data values from the [Steam Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API)?

For example, from `GetPlayerAchievements` I also want the name and description.

So far I use this URL: `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=MYAPPID&key=MYKEY&steamid=MYSTEAMID`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `&l=en` to the end of your URL. This adds the language dependent fields of `name` and `description` to the results.

`en` can be substituted for other supported languages

Example for a player's Team Fortress 2 stats:

URL: `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=MYAPPID&key=MYKEY&steamid=MYSTEAMID&l=en`

Returns a JSON result that has this block in the `['playerstats']['achievements']` array

```
{
    "apiname": "TF_PLAY_GAME_EVERYCLASS",
    "achieved": 1,
    "name": "Head of the Class",
    "description": "Play a complete round with every class."
}
```